# Wait inside While with ManualResetEvent

Tags: c#, manualresetevent

I have an operation via `While` that i want to Freeze:

```
    do
    {
        ManualResetEvent.Reset(); // Here i want to wait

        // Here i am doing my stuff...
    }

    while (some boolean value);
}
```

My `ManualResetEvent` :

```
private static ManualResetEvent _manualResetEvent;

public static ManualResetEvent ManualResetEvent
{
    get { return _manualResetEvent; }
    set { _manualResetEvent = value; }
}

ManualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

In some point in my code via `Button` i just want to freeze my operation:

```
private void btnPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ManualResetEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

Is this the right way to do that ?

Comment: Depends on what your thread is, if it is your UI thread you can't block it like that.

Comment: No this is not UI thread

Comment: Have you thought of using a Threading.Timer and CancellationToken combination? This would give the same functionality without blocking a thread.

Answer (score 2):

You have your two functions backwards. The loop you want to wait needs to use the `.WaitOne()`. Also, if you want it to run at the start you need to initialize the reset event to `true`

init

```
private static ManualResetEvent _manualResetEvent;

public static ManualResetEvent ManualResetEvent
{
    get { return _manualResetEvent; }
    set { _manualResetEvent = value; }
}

ManualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true); //Set it to true to let it run at the start.
```

loop

```
    do
    {
        ManualResetEvent.WaitOne(); // Here i want to wait

        // Here i am doing my stuff...
    }

    while (some boolean value);
}
```

elsewhere

```
private void btnPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ManualResetEvent.Reset();
}
private void btnUnPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ManualResetEvent.Set();
}
```